# Converting MKMapRect.origin to longitude and latitude

Tags: swift, mkmaprect

I have a need to annotate a visible point on a map(without user input). I am using MKMapView `visibleMapRect` to calculate the point I want. However from my codes below, I am reading values like

```
let rect = mapView.visibleMapRect
print(rect.origin.x) //211653840.83766
print(rect.origin.y) //133214809.161136
```

which are not longitude and latitude. But any example I found of conversion between MKMapRect and Coordinates does it like as though the origin is already given in longitude and latitude. Is there something I need to do to get longitude and latitude from `visibleMapRect`? Or is there a formula to convert those values I am getting in longitude and latitude?

For additional information the longitude and latitude of a visible point is:

```
103.861463   //longitude
1.3165999    //latitude
```

when the visibleMapRect is:

```
211653840.83766   //origin.x
133214809.161136  //origin.y
16865.6084111989  //size.width
26357.4158187151  //size.height
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let rect = mapView.visibleMapRect
let mapPoint = MKMapPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)
let coordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(mapPoint)
print(coordinate.latitude)
print(coordinate.longitude)
```

Comment: that's... a simple solution I totally missed. Thanks

Comment: @BenOng Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Haha, just now there was that buffer time before I could accept.

Comment: How can I get the latitude and longitude of the Top-left corner and bottom-right corner of the MapView?